# ini file cannot be written using resource mode

Tags: qt

```
cfgSetting = new QSettings(":/Src/devConfig.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

cfgSetting = new QSettings("C:\\filePath \\Src\\devConfig.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
```

`cfgSetting->setVal("Group/key", "value");` has no effect when I load the file in the first way.But the second way has an effect. I really want to know why. And I would like to use the first way to achieve it. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Resource files and configuration files are not really meant to be used together.

The resource files are embedded into the binary file at the compilation (the `.exe` on windows), so you should consider the resource files as read-only.

The configuration files are files that are supposed to save/load configuration options and store those options (on the computers file system) between different executions of your application.

Note: you can store the `.ini` file in the same folder as the application, you can use [applicationDirPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) to get the path and set it to your QSettings instance by using [setPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#setPath), or you can set [QSettings::Scope](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings-2) to let Qt manage the path and you just decide if you want user or system scope:

```
QSettings settings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "MyOrganization", "MyProduct");
```

Comment: "you should consider the resource files as read-only" Because that is what they are, there's no way to write to them. :)  A word of caution about storing data files in the application directory is that on some OSs (Mac/Win/mobile), in some configurations, this folder will not be accessible to the user running the application. It is typically best to store settings in the default/recommended places as described by QSettings docs, unless one is fully aware of all the implications on the target platform(s).